# List of API commands for Win32api

Tags: python, api

I recently found the add-on for Python called "win32api". I am very pleased with it.. But only problem is i can't seem to find any lists that list all the possible API calls that you can make from that add-on. I have tried looking through an API reference (http://www.andreavb.com/API_List.html), but most of the commands were not working, although some were. Are there any other lists like that specifially for this add-on out there? Or just general lists?

I hope someone can help,

Jake.

Comment: I already looked at one on this forum for IronPython, but i am interested in using the standard python.

Comment: That andreavb.com site looks pretty sketchy to me. What's wrong with MSDN for Win32 API reference? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fire up the interpreter:

```
import moduleX
dir(moduleX)
help(moduleX)
```

Answer (score 0):

visit the PyWin32 documentation site: [Win32api docu](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html)

If you need examples for some functions goto: `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32\Demos`